# Poisson regression model in R

Tags: r, regression, poisson-regression, poisson-distribution

I am working on a uni assessment with COVID-19 topic and trying to work out a poisson regression for COVID 19 pandemic.

My predictor is the number of confimred cases as count, my predictors in the poisson regression is outbreak_days, apple_drivingmobility, country.

Then model comes with a gigantic AIC and also deviance.

Is that because my confimred cases are culmulatives which wont follow poisson distribution? instead, should I use new cases each day? Or this is entirely not suitable to use poisson.

```
glm(formula = confirmed_deaths ~ outbreak_days + Apple_DrivingMobility +
 country, family = poisson(link = log), data = df_cleaned_driving_level)
Deviance Residuals:
 Min 1Q Median 3Q Max
-131.981 -9.773 -0.863 3.798 87.411
Coefficients:
 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) 1.726e+00 1.795e-02 96.183 <2e-16 ***
outbreak_days 6.706e-02 3.687e-05 1818.954 <2e-16 ***
Apple_DrivingMobility -1.847e-02 4.573e-05 -403.834 <2e-16 ***
countryBelgium 4.404e+00 1.791e-02 245.852 <2e-16 ***
countryBrazil 4.604e+00 1.789e-02 257.378 <2e-16 ***
countryCanada 3.755e+00 1.806e-02 207.950 <2e-16 ***
countryCzechia 1.746e+00 2.048e-02 85.283 <2e-16 ***
countryDenmark 2.431e+00 1.934e-02 125.720 <2e-16 ***
countryEstonia 4.712e-01 2.768e-02 17.020 <2e-16 ***
countryFinland 1.693e+00 2.109e-02 80.292 <2e-16 ***
countryFrance 4.922e+00 1.788e-02 275.355 <2e-16 ***
countryGermany 4.186e+00 1.796e-02 232.992 <2e-16 ***
countryIreland 2.447e+00 1.839e-02 133.051 <2e-16 ***
countryItaly 4.871e+00 1.791e-02 272.003 <2e-16 ***
countryJapan 8.318e-01 2.285e-02 36.399 <2e-16 ***
countryLuxembourg 2.099e-01 2.338e-02 8.979 <2e-16 ***
countryMexico 3.551e+00 1.806e-02 196.676 <2e-16 ***
countryNetherlands 4.098e+00 1.797e-02 228.088 <2e-16 ***
countryNewZealand -1.148e+00 4.103e-02 -27.984 <2e-16 ***
countryNorway 1.440e+00 2.145e-02 67.110 <2e-16 ***
countryPhilippines 1.448e+00 1.893e-02 76.457 <2e-16 ***
countrySingapore -2.988e+00 7.258e-02 -41.170 <2e-16 ***
countrySlovakia -8.289e-01 3.875e-02 -21.393 <2e-16 ***
countrySpain 4.975e+00 1.790e-02 277.988 <2e-16 ***
countrySweden 4.060e+00 1.827e-02 222.273 <2e-16 ***
countrySwitzerland 3.208e+00 1.829e-02 175.383 <2e-16 ***
countryTaiwan* -1.535e+00 5.629e-02 -27.272 <2e-16 ***
countryUnitedKingdom 5.153e+00 1.785e-02 288.619 <2e-16 ***
countryUnitedStates 6.537e+00 1.783e-02 366.664 <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes: 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)
 Null deviance: 20309689 on 1879 degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 765387 on 1851 degrees of freedom
AIC: 777730
Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: This question is more suitable for the stats stack exchange site, but you should certainly be using daily counts rather than cumulative counts for a Poisson regression

Answer (score 1):

AIC is dependent on loglikelihood: AIC = 2k - 2 ln(L), where L is the log-likelihood. Deviance -2*L and k is the number of parameter in the model.

In the poisson glm, you obtain the loglikelihood by summing up the probabilities for the observations, given your predicted values. You can read more about it [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/316763/log-likelihood-function-in-poisson-regression) So the more observations you have, the larger your AIC. AIC is only useful for comparing models.

Sum of poisson is still a poisson, so it doesn't matter. The one thing you can do is check whether they are over or underdispersed, you can check out some of the approaches [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66586/is-there-a-test-to-determine-whether-glm-overdispersion-is-significant). Otherwise I think the model is ok because you have one categorical variable (countries) that has many levels, and it is essential to use that.

Comment: Hi there,
Thanks for your help. I just went through the dispersontest and the rest is as below, looks like this is dispersed?: Overdispersion test

data:  model
z = 15.447, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true alpha is greater than 0
sample estimates:
   alpha 
358.3246

Comment: yeah its overdispersed... If you are trying to predict, what you have now is ok. If you need to infer, i.e say something about the significance of the variable, you can use family = quasipoisson . What are you trying to get from the model?

Answer (score 1):

> Then model comes with a gigantic AIC and also deviance.
>
> Is that because my confimred cases are culmulatives which wont follow poisson distribution? instead, should I use new cases each day? Or this is entirely not suitable to use poison.

The AIC and deviance are not judged based on their absolute size, but instead, we look at *differences* in AIC and deviance.

The AIC can differ in sample size (flipping 1 heads in 2 coin tosses is more likely than flipping 20 heads in 20 coin tosses) and also because the likelihood function (on which AIC is based) can be scaled by a random number.